# Would Rather Do than Doing?

Tags: grammar

Is it alright to write this?

I would rather swim than going to the party.

Comment: "I would rather swim than go to the party" or even "I would rather go swimming than go to the party". The modal *would* takes a bare infinitive

Comment: After Than always a bare infintif?

Comment: What's a bare infintif? Doesn't sound very appetizing.

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather swim than going to the party.

It is incorrect. Let's reverse the verb forms.

*I would rather swimming than go to the party.*

If that doesn't sound wrong to you then I'll give the reasoning.

**Answer**

When you use the structure:  *I would rather X than Y,* then X and Y must  match in grammatical terms.

So we can say:

*I would rather **swim** than **go** [to the party].*

or

*I would rather **go** [swimming] than **go** [to the party].*

You cannot mix the verb forms.

---

Note: If you want to use the gerund then you could say something like:

*I prefer swimming to partying.*

but you still have to match the two parts.